# UIBezierPath addLineToPoint has incorrect thickness

Tags: uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a shape using basic straight lines with UIBezierPath. When the shape is rendered, though, the bottom line seems to be "doubled", or otherwise not respecting its thickness. A picture will help tell the story:

[image]

And the code:

```
  #define height 170
  #define width 70
  #define linewidth 5

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  UIBezierPath *leftPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

  [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
  leftPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapSquare;
  leftPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinBevel;
  leftPath.lineWidth = linewidth;

  [leftPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
  [leftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0)];
  [leftPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

  [leftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, height)];
  [leftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height)];

  [leftPath stroke];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this mattered, but I was drawing this in a view that was larger than the height of the path. When I drew the path in a view equal to that path's height, the width of the path was no longer incorrect.